How to create a private cluster on Solana?
I want to have a private cluster (not linked with mainnet) for my application, the primary use case is to create investor wallets, create NFTs and transfer of these NFTs on blockchain.
I want to have 2 to 3 nodes, in case one is down other will be there. I will deploy the cluster on AWS.
Any idea, docs, tips how to got about it ? What should be the ideal way to go about it ?
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

you could use devnet for this

These are the basic steps:

Set up AWS infrastructure (Provision 2 to 3 EC2 instances)
Install Solana software (SSH into each EC2 instance)
Configure and Bootstrap the Cluster
Monitor and Maintain the Cluster
Deploy Applications on Your Private Cluster

You can read more about it here  => https://docs.solanalabs.com/clusters/#creating-a-cluster

This is an excellent answer, and to add some more info about how to do this easily, check out the "net" scripts in the validator repo: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/net
